# .htaccess RewriteRule works but my css doesnt work in that page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

.htaccess file code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^book/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ book.php?isbn=$1
RewriteRule ^book/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ book.php?isbn=$1
```

It works but the css files, images files, JS files linked with it doesn't work. The Page come without any css formatting. The url to my website is given below please help

[Link to My Page using this](http://www.booksiders.com/book/9780545010221)

I want that an address which is like "www.booksiders.com/book.php?isbn=9780545010221" to appear like "www.booksiders.com/book/9780545010221"

and this is working but somehow the linked files are not working.

Comment: Please provide more details, like the links that dont work and the error code.

Comment: There is no error. Its just that my css isn't working after using RewriteRule

Answer (score 1):

You have problem not with rewrite rules.

Change

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/any.css" />
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/any.css" />
```

because browser think that he has to load **book/css/any.css**, but must load **/css/any.css**